# SQLlite database, insert punct after second digit

Tags: java, sql

I have a sqlite databse, with alot of tables. Each table has many rows. In one column I have something like this:

```
[58458, 65856, 75658, 98456, 98578, ... N]
```

I made a mistake when created the databse (I don't have acces to the initial data anymore ), what I need is to make these numbers with a punct after the second digit and have something like this:

```
[58.458, 65.856, 75.658, 98.456, 98.578, ... N]
```

Is there any way I can do this? I prefer Java. Or is it already any tools that can do this?

Comment: are they all 5 digit numbers?

Comment: Yes, but hte problem is, that it's a not NUMERCI columnt, it's just a simple text field with alot of numbers in it separated with a comma.

Comment: Ok, so you need to parse each column that looks like [58458, 65856, 75658, 98456, 98578, ... N] and edit the numbers inside, and after that update the columns, the final result being a simple text field also?

Comment: Does the column pattern contain the [1, 2, 3], or is it is like 1, 2, 3 . Also, do you have a space after each comma?

Comment: It's [1, 2, 3]. Yeah, there is a space after each comma.

Comment: I made you a function that you can use to parse and convert the string from the simple text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to parse the information from each column.

```
public static String convertColumn(String textF)
{


    String textAux = "";
    String newText = "[";

    int i = 0;

    textF = textF.substring(1, textF.length() - 1);

    while(i < textF.length())
    {
        textAux = textF.substring(i, i + 5);
        int nrAux = Integer.parseInt(textAux);

        i+=7;
        int a;
        int b;

        a = nrAux / 1000;
        b = nrAux - a * 1000;

        double newNr;
        newNr = a + b * 0.001;
        newText = newText + newNr + ", ";

    }
    newText = newText.substring(0, newText.length() - 2);
    newText += "]";
    return newText;
}
```

The function will have as parameter a string like [58458, 65856, 75658, 98456, 98578], which you will get from 
the SQL table, and the return value will be [58.458, 65.856, 75.658, 98.456, 98.578] which is the value that you need to update the column with.

For SQL the base idea is this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = convertColumn(column);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if it's a NUMERIC column:

```
UPDATE <TABLE NAME> SET <COLUMN> = <COLUMN>/1000;
```

If it is NOT a NUMERIC or REAL column then this should work:

```
UPDATE <TABLE NAME> SET <COLUMN> = CAST(<COLUMN> AS REAL)/1000;
```

(Thanks to Goibniu for the pointer)

Comment: Thanks,but hte problem is that it's a not NUMERIC columnt, it's just a simple text field with alot of numbers in it separated with a comma.

Comment: Ah I understand your problem now. Yes, that is more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CAST as REAL on the column, and then update as advised in the other answer.

```
select CAST(YOUR_COL AS REAL) from YOUR_TABLE
```

Search for CAST in this doc for more info on it: [SQLite language guide](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)